# Adding " @nguniversal/express-engine" in an existing Angular project gives error "this.tree.readText" is not a function

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

I was trying to make client side angular project to change it to SSR(Server Side Rendering) by adding `ng add @nguniversal/express-engine` in an existing Angular project but it gave error of "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/workspace'" and after installing @schematics/angular, it is now giving error "this.tree.readText" is not a function.